# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background ...') when add placeautocomplete compile

Tags: android, google-api, android-gradle-plugin, placeautocompletefragment

i got a problem.

When i add compile for PlaceAutocomplete my project give an error

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
 compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
 compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
```

This is my app.gradle:

[app.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ5TM.png)

the error that is shown is the following:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaYR2.png)

And the error is in multiple file, one of them is:

[error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG8rF.png)

This file is generated when i build project. I already try to clean prject and rebuild but nothing happens.

Someone can tell me what the problem is?
If you need anything else, ask

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't use** these libraries with compileSdk 17.

Use `compileSdkVersion 27`.